# Using nodemailer with G suite

Tags: email, gmail, nodemailer

I have tried using nodemailer with gmail and it works. I tried to use the same code with my G suite name@mydomain.com email and there's bad credentials error. Is there an easy way to use nodemailer with G suite? because I want my business mail to be seen as sender.
this is the code I am using:

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'name@business.com',
    pass: 'password'
  }
});

exports.sendMail = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
cors(req, res, () => {

    // getting dest email by query string
    const dest = req.query.dest;

    const mailOptions = {
        from: 'Your Account Name <aegegwgwg@gmail.com>', // Something like: Jane Doe <janedoe@gmail.com>
        to: dest,
        subject: 'I\'M A PICKLE!!!', // email subject
        html: `<p style="font-size: 16px;">Pickle Riiiiiiiiiiiiiiiick!!</p>
            <br />
            <img src="https://images.prod.meredith.com/product/fc8754735c8a9b4aebb786278e7265a5/1538025388228/l/rick-and-morty-pickle-rick-sticker" />
        ` // email content in HTML
    };

    // returning result
    return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (erro, info) => {
        if(erro){
            return res.send(erro.toString());
        }
        return res.send('Sended');
    });
});    
});
```